# Не передать текст с кавычками в xpath локатор selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Есть текст.

```
var1 = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'
```

Есть запрос.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='"+var1+"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']").click()
Не находит элемент.
```

НО запрос

```
//a[text()='ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']
```

Находит нужный элемент. ХОТЯ ОНИ ИДЕНТИЧНЫ.

С переменной python выдает следующее в консоли:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']"}
```

И если скопировать запрос, на который ругается питон и попробовать найти им элемент в хроме - ИЩЕТ!

Вопрос. Как передать переменную, чтобы элемент искало. Элемент ТОЧНО находится в видимости и ТОЧНО уже загрузился. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил форматирование текста.

Работает?

```
var1 = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[text()='{var1}']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']").click()
```

---

**UPD.**

Открыл локально кусок HTML и xpath нашел элемент

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(r'C:\Users\ipetrash\Projects\SimplePyScripts\_FOO_TEST_TEST\1.html')

nameOrg = 'ТСЖ "ВОЛГОГРАДСКИЙ ПР-Т 50-1, 52-1, 52-2, 56-1, 56-2, 58-1, 58-3, 60-2, 64-1, 64-2, 66-2, ВОЛЖСКИЙ 21"'

text = "//a[text()='{nameOrg}']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']".format(nameOrg=nameOrg)
print(text)

el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(text)
print(el)
```

Пруф:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, ведь вы взяли переменную в текст.

Comment: Странно, должно работать. Можете приложить пример на котором можно поиграться?

Comment: Подправил, но все равно не работает. То же самое, питон пишет, что не может найти элемент по "такому" запросу, но если скопировать xpath и вручную найти им в хроме, то ищет
`text = "//a[text()='{nameOrg}']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'chakra-stack') and contains(@class,'css-1oap1wr')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::button[text()='Отклонить']".format(nameOrg = nameOrg)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(text).click()`

Comment: А что в `print(text)` выдает? И все-же хотелось бы пример поиграться, мб я что-то нашел бы. Если нельзя страницу (мб там авторизовываться еще нужно), то хотя бы кусок html, чтобы на нем поиграться

Comment: Выдает нормальный текст, который грузится. 
https://dropmefiles.com/wwQB6 Кусок того элемента.

Comment: Локальный файл открыл, тот xpath нашел элемент. Мб вы не дождались прогрузки страницы и/или появления того элемента? Если дело в том, что элемент еще не успел появиться, добавьте `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`, чтобы было ожидание при поиске элементов

Comment: Нет, элемент находит точно. Если я просто поставлю //button[text()='Отклонить']
То он его находит с теми же настройками. Но стоит добавить в путь имя орг. с кавычками - все, не находит. Дело еще может быть в том, что у вас Фаерфокс, а у меня Хром. ПЛЮС, очень важный момент - я подцепляю имя организации из excel

Comment: Попробуйте с другого конца подойти к задаче. Сделайте поиск того элемента по другим признакам и выведите его `text` и сравните ваш `nameOrg` с тем текстом. Для лучшей проверки значений используйте `repr`, например: print(repr(nameOrg)). Так можно будет посмотреть где расходится текст. Если оно абсолютно одинаковое, тогда даже не знаю, разве что снова смотреть в xpath, мб что-то с кавычками сделать